# "To keep up -- a new and exciting..." why this sentence is split up?

Tags: punctuation

[THE SOURCE](https://books.google.jo/books?id=pfB9VsrdX4IC&pg=PA23&dq=becker%20found%20himself%20struggling%20to%20keep%20up%20a%20new%20and%20exciting%20experience%20for%20him&hl=ar&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiL0KvhnfLWAhWkKsAKHfJfBVsQ6AEIIzAA#v=onepage&q=becker%20found%20himself%20struggling%20to%20keep%20up%20a%20new%20and%20exciting%20experience%20for%20him&f=false)

> Becker found himself struggling to keep up — a new and exciting experience for him.

Why is the sentence split up? I mean why the writer separate the phrasal verb "keep up" from "a new and exciting..."?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually after a dash, what follows is a separate clause or a parenthetical remark unrelated to the grammar of the clause before the dash.  Here, "a new and exciting experience for him" is a comment on the situation.  It's not the object of "keep up".

"Keep up" here is used intransitively.

The sentence could be paraphrased as:

> Becker found himself struggling to get things done fast enough - which was a new and exciting experience for him.